# Join attributes by location and filter via Python

Tags: pyqgis

Join attributes by location and filter via Python

I want to do a spatial join between 2 shapes. Then I want to work on the new join table, I want to make a filter if the field of "ID pa" has the same value so the field of "ref_chambre" must neither be "OHN" and must not contain the value 1 and 2. I did a test on the join and here is the script.

```
from qgis.core import *

from qgis.utils import *

import os, sys

import processing

NAN_CHAMBRE = "C:\Users\melouaer\ing\jointure/NAN_CHAMBRE.shp"

ZONE_PA = "C:\Users\melouaer\ing\jointure/ZONE_PA.shp"

result = "C:\Users\melouaer\ing\jointure/result.shp"

general.runalg("qgis:joinattributesbylocation", NAN_CHAMBRE , ZONE_PA u'intersects', 0, 0, '', 1, result)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Manel! Are you wanting to run the code inside QGIS (e.g. the Python Console) or outside QGIS (e.g. OSGeo4W Shell)?